# How can I position these javascripts next to eachother using divs?

Tags: html, css

Ok. I've gone to many places to find an answer, and I've tried many of these. I have this website, and I need two lines of code positioned next to each other. You can see my attempt at the bottom of the code.

http://pastebin.com/mV1DUbg0

I tried to paste it in, but it looked pretty weird so I just put it in pastebin!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want the two `<script>` scripts right next to each other? Why don't you just put them in one file, then?

Comment: Do you want to set <div class="left"> beside <div class="right"> ???

Comment: You are missing closing </div> tag for <div class="left">. Close this tag and <div class="right"> will jump next to it.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a closing </div> for <div class="left">. Just close that and your two lines will be positioned next to each other.